# Add extension filter for StringProperty with FILE_PATH subtype

Tags: interface, file-browser

I have a file select property I am using, defined like so:

```
psa_filepath: StringProperty(default='', subtype='FILE_PATH', update=on_psa_filepath_updated)
```

The `on_psa_filepath_updated` function loads and inspects the file to list out its contents so that the user can choose what elements to import.

[image]

Unfortunately, I see no way to tell the file dialog for this property to have extension filtering (in this case I only want to see `*.psa` files).

I am aware of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/add-a-filter-for-the-extension-of-a-file-in-the-file-browser) that asks the same thing, but the top answer does not directly address the question.

It seems like massive overkill to require users to create a whole separate file select operator just to get basic functionality like this. Is there a way to do this more succinctly?

Comment: I don't think there is a way unfortunately, and I think the answer is right in pointing that one has to implement a custom operator to do extension filtering.

Comment: Are you writing your own PSA importer? If you're working with an existing addon, which one?

Comment: I have written my own add-on to both import and export PSK and PSA files. The existing importers and exporters are insufficient for our team's workflow. The link is here: https://github.com/DarklightGames/io_export_psk_psa The importer functionality is currently on a dev branch.